# Change variable outside the method

Tags: python-3.x, variables

I have code like this

```
variable =0
def functio(var):
    var += 2
    return boolean
functio(variable)
```

But var doesn’t change.
I pass different variables to method so global wouldn’t work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters are always passed by assignement in Python, so if you give functio() a variable, inside functio() it will only be this variable's value.

One way to get around this is by wrapping your variable inside a list to use a reference, like so:

```
variable = [0]
def functio(var):
    var[0] += 2
    return boolean
functio(variable)
```

Because the list contains pointers to its element's address in memory, the scope does not matter.

Edit: more ways to do this [here](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference)